# Simple Way to get angles

Tags: java

I made a program that asks the user for 3 lengths and determines if it is equilateral, scalene, isosceles.
I want to know how to calculate angles (all 3 sides are given) in Java so that the program determines if it is obtuse or acute or right-angled. Please help me out.

The edit actually provides a way to do it, so please no more downvotes.
Suggestions welcome.

```
double pi = 3.14159265359;// value of pi

double angle = Math.round(Math.acos((b*b + c*c - a*a) / (2.0*b*c)) * (180.0 / pi)); // discovering angles
double angle2 = Math.round(Math.acos((a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2.0*a*c)) * (180.0 / pi));
double angle3 = Math.round(180 - (angle2 + angle));
```

Comment: Your question might be a geometry question and not a programming one. Do you have a mathematical answer already? If not, the first thing towards a solution would be to read about geometry and trigonometry. If you have a mathematical solution, have you made attempts to implement it?

Comment: +bli If I am not mistaken math and programming go together, and read the whole question what I am asking is a way to solve something because I know that Java has one. Please delete your comment. Btw I am never asking questions without researching or implementing(I know my math well).

Comment: Ok, so your question is actually an implementation one. Probably you could have shown the code that you already have and the maths that you want to translate into java, so that people were guided towards a more specific way of answering. I guess this would have reduced the number of people downvoting the question for it looking too broad (I didn't downvote).

Comment: bli thanks for the response. New to StackOverflow and it looks like people are just hunting questions to downvote.Thanks for not downvoting and for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the sides of the triangle, you can find the angles just by following steps below...

- use The [Law of Cosines](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html) first to calculate one of the angles
- then use The Law of Cosines again to find another angle
- and finally use [angles of a triangle add to 180°](https://www.mathsisfun.com/proof180deg.html) to find the last
  angle.

In java you can use `Math.acos(val)` to calculate the Inverse Cosine.

Comment: Rimon awesome so in the bracket of Math.acos what will be placed.Instead of value, will it just be length.Basicaly just put the length a and b instead of value. Last step is to subtract the total of two from 180. Does it give value in degree.

Comment: suppose you want to calculate angle A then the formula for that is `cosA = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / 2bc` so the `A = Math.acos( (b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / 2bc)`.
you will get the value of A in Radians. if you want to get that in Degree then you just need to multiply `180*Math.PI` with it.

[see this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html) for clear understanding...